# Git Subproject / Gitlink / Submodule - Remove and Keep files, commit with Master

Tags: wordpress, git, git-submodules, subproject

I am creating a repo to save a wordpress starter package for client websites using FoundationPress as the starter theme.

I cloned the repo into my themes folder, and it is not committing files into my master repo, is this a gitlink or submodule?

I can't figure out how to remove the gitlink/subproject/submodule and include it in the main package.

Trying to remove the submodule I get:

`No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'wp-content/themes/FoundationPress'`

I don't have a `.gitmodules` file

[image]

Do I need to add it as a submodule, then remove it? I've wasted so much time on this already, please help!

Thank you.